# Alternative to Web Mercator projection that does not look too small on phone?

Tags: coordinate-system, web-mercator

My issue with Web Mercator as a projection to use online is that I think it gives people an unrealistic perception of space. Greenland looking massive is a good example.

One benefit of Web Mercator, with Leaflet etc, is the projection is endless in each horizontal direction, meaning it's OK for small and large screens alike.

I've looked at using Robinson in D3, but it's going to look too small on phone.

Is there a viable alternative for the web that doesn't use the Mercator projection, but doesn't look tiny on phone, as I'm thinking the Robinson/Eckert projections might do?

Comment: All projections distort in some way. You haven't really stated which parts of the world are more important to look big/small relative to others.

Comment: Yeah I understand they all distort in some way. I'm only looking for a better solution, not a perfect solution Just closer to a sphere. I'm making a map of the world with no particular interest in any one area. I actually don't know which polygons I'll be using ATM, so can't answer that yet. For a whole world perspective, I thought Robinson would be a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, I extract two properties :

1. must fit in a rectangle (so that you can duplicate along the
   horizantl direction and turn around the Earth without adjusting the
   center of projection). This will not be the case with Robinson or
   Eckert
2. must preserve areas: you don't want a huge Greenland

Therefore I suggest cylindrical equal area, but this will squeeze the high latitude

Comment: OK, I think I've decided on Gall-Peters, which is a variant.